# How do I do a JavaScript script that checks an input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, button, jsx

I wanna do a React site that allows the user to enter a number into an `input` and when I click the button `Verificar` the function `Aleatorio` is called. This function has a JavaScript script that render a random number and check if the user hits the number.

But when I enter a number and click on the button, nothing happens.

I think the if statement is being disregarded, 'cause every other thing in the code is perfect.

Here's the code

```
export function Main() {
    return(
        <>
            <h1>Seja bem vindo a loteria, carregue <a>aqui</a> para conhecer as regras</h1>
            <h2>Introduza um número de 0 a 10 na caixa abaixo</h2>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Número" />
            <input type="button" value="Validar" onClick={Aleatorio} />
            <p id="res">yooo</p>
        </>
    )
}

function Aleatorio(num = document.getElementById('nmb-num'))
{
    let x = Number(num)
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0 + 1) + 0)         
        if (num== random){
            window.alert('Parabéns, acertaste!')
        } else if (num < random){
            window.alert('Tás quase, tente um número maior')
        } 
        if (num > random){
            window.alert('Tás quase, tente um número menor')
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your script is in the argument of the callback function `Aleatorio`.

In React, the callback function used for the prop `onClick` takes by default an argument which is the event (the click) and not a DOM element (like in your case `document.getElementById('nmb-num')`). Since in your scenario you won't need to use the event argument, then you don't have to pass anything to your function.

There are 2 other issues that your code was having:

**1)** You should access the value field of the input element to get the number of the user. So for instance it should be:

```js
document.getElementById("nmb-num").value
```

**2)** You forgot to add the relevant id attribute to the input (id="nmb-num")

### Complete code:

```
export default function Main() {
  function Aleatorio() {
    let x = parseInt(document.getElementById("nmb-num").value);
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0 + 1) + 0);
    if (x === random) {
      window.alert("Parabéns, acertaste!");
    } else if (x < random) {
      window.alert("Tás quase, tente um número maior");
    }
    if (x > random) {
      window.alert("Tás quase, tente um número menor");
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        Seja bem vindo a loteria, carregue <a>aqui</a> para conhecer as regras
      </h1>
      <h2>Introduza um número de 0 a 10 na caixa abaixo</h2>
      <input id="nmb-num" type="number" placeholder="Número" />
      <input type="button" value="Validar" onClick={Aleatorio} />
      <p id="res">yooo</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use state to store the input's value.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
export function Main() {
    const [val, setVal] = useState('');
    function Aleatorio() {
        const x = +val;
        const random = Math.random() * 11 | 0;
        if (x < random) alert('Tás quase, tente um número maior');
        else if(x > random) alert('Tás quase, tente um número menor');
        else alert('Parabéns, acertaste!');
    }
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Seja bem vindo a loteria, carregue <a>aqui</a> para conhecer as regras</h1>
            <h2>Introduza um número de 0 a 10 na caixa abaixo</h2>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Número" value={val} onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="button" value="Validar" onClick={Aleatorio} />
            <p id="res">yooo</p>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function Aleatorio() you have used document.getElementById() which applies to normal DOM. if you want an equivalent function you can use the useRef hook as explained in [React Documentation](https://react.dev/learn/escape-hatches).

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export function Main() {
  const numRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        Seja bem-vindo à loteria, carregue <a href="#">aqui</a> para conhecer as regras
      </h1>
      <h2>Introduza um número de 0 a 10 na caixa abaixo</h2>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Número" ref={numRef} />
      <input type="button" value="Validar" onClick={Aleatorio} />
      <p id="res">yooo</p>
    </>
  );
  
  function Aleatorio(){
    let x = Number(numRef.current.value);
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0 + 1) + 0);
    
    if (x === random) {
      window.alert('Parabéns, acertaste!');
    } else if (x < random) {
      window.alert('Tás quase, tente um número maior');
    } else if (x > random) {
      window.alert('Tás quase, tente um número menor');
    }
  };
}
```